# can't retrieve woocommerce product data in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, woocommerce

I'm just trying to get sample product data from `woocommerce` API.

this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import Api from './WooCommerce/Api.js'

export default class FetchExample extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.state.date.name}</Text>

            </View>
        );
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState.date = Api.get('products/122609')


    }
}



AppRegistry.registerComponent('fetchExample', () => FetchExample);
```

**And here is a error:**

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise your state with default values inside of your constructor:

```
this.state = { date: '...' };
```

Then change your state updating logic from direct assignment to `this.setState`, since direct assignment will lead to unexpected behaviour:

```
this.setState({ date: Api.get('products/122609') });
```